# Ionic 2 - Get file path from component class

Tags: android, file, cordova, share, ionic2

I'm using the **Social Sharing** plugin and I need to make reference to a mp3 file from a component class (with typescript).

The mp3 file is located under

```
platforms/android/assets/www/assets/song.mp3
```

From my class I tried a couple of different paths such as *file://assets/www/assets/song.mp3* and a lot of variations but none of them worked. However, if I put a url from my server, it'll work, so the issue here is definetly finding the path to my file.

Maybe using another plugin that could retrieve me this path or any other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the correct path is directly 'www/assets/song.mp3', it was a matter of keep trying different alternatives until I hit the correct one. Silly answer for a silly question.